# Quickly get coverage of each position in arrary

Tags: python, java, algorithm, intervals

It is a short problem, There is a list of intervals, for example:

```
[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]
```

I want to get the coverage, which means number of intervals that overlap on the current position of each position from smallest to largest number (1 to 6)(like a line sweep from 1 to 6 and get number of hits at each position), the result should be:

```
[1,2,3,3,2,1]
```

Is there any way to quickly find this out, I can iterate all positions and see if it is in each interval, but that is too slow, is there any way to get this quick? Because in practice there can be millions of intervals, I am thinking of representing each interval as bit arrary but still cannot figure out, if anyone has idea, please let me know Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You could map your set of intervals in a set of number pairs `(time; delta)`

```
[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]
```

becomes

```
(1;+1), (4;-1), (2;+1), (5;-1), (3;+1), (6;-1)
```

Then sort the set of pairs in ascending order of their time entries

```
(1;+1), (2;+1), (3;+1), (4;-1), (5;-1), (6;-1)
```

Finally, go through this list and increment/decrement the coverage count, initialized at zero:

```
(1;1), (2;2), (3;3), (4;2), (5;1), (6;0)
```

Comment: Nice algorithm. I think you are confusing things by introducing time (which OP never mentions). Also the question is using inclusive ranges whereas your example is exclusive of the end of the range. An easy fix by just adding 1 to the end pairs.